# NodeJS/MongoDB how to get the ObjectId when using findOne()

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try to get the ObjectId withing my application by using the `findOne()`-method of `MongoDB` but keep getting the error: `Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters` and I have no clue what happens.

Here is the code:

Angular:

```
$scope.edit = function(id){
    $http.get('/countries/' + id ).success(function(response){
        $scope.countries = response;
    })
}
```

NodeJS / MongoDB:

```
app.get('/countries/:id', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  db.countries.findOne({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function(err, doc) {
     res.json(doc);
  });
});
```

Can someone maybe tell me what I'm doing wrong??

**UPDATE**: It turns out that the problem was that I had to change the `$scope.countries` to `$scope.country` since the `edit`-button is defined like:

```
<button ng-click="edit(country._id)">Edit country</button>
```

So I was able to solve it myself. Sorry for the inconvenience...

But HUUUGE thanks for everyone who was trying to help, I really appreciate it

Comment: What is `id` / `req.params.id`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills see my updated code

Comment: [`mongojs`](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs) "autocasts" to `ObjectId` for you for values issued in queries or other operations on the `_id` field. So you don't need to cast it. But of course the other side of this is that clearly you are not using an `ObjectId` in your `_id` or as input from `req.params.id`

Comment: This still doesn't give us an example of what `id` passed into the countries is

Comment: @ExplosionPills It's clearly either a plain string that does not conform to an `ObjectId` or a "numeric" value. The `mongojs` library being used does not allow any other data type within the `_id` field. AFAIK.

Comment: Display the value when you console.log(id) so we know what the value is that you are using.

Comment: It's likely that your id is already an object.. What does `db.countries.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, doc) {
     res.json(doc);
  });` do?